# WIX API response

Tags: velo

I have the following function in my WIX website, which is making a request to an external API:

```
export function current_pull(page, per_page, filter_mode, view_id) {

 const url_request = URL + page + '&per_page=' + per_page + '&filtermode=' + filter_mode + '&view_id=' + view_id;

 return fetch(url_request, {        
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
            'X-AUTH-TOKEN': API_KEY,
            'X-SUBDOMAIN': SUBDOMAIN
        },
 }).then(function(response) {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        console.log("current answered");
        var items = response.json();
        console.log(items);
    } else {
        console.log("there was an error" + response.statusText);
    }
 })
 .catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
 });
}
```

The `console.log(items);` outputs:

```
Promise {
_c: [],
_a: undefined,
_s: 0,
_d: false,
_v: undefined,
_h: 0,
_n: false }
```

How do I get the actual API response

Answer (score 1):

`response.json()` is also a `Promise` so in this case you need to change your code as follows:

```
response.json().then(items => console.log(items))
```

You may check further documentation here: [Body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)